# Entity Framework - Call stored procedure with default parameters

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have some stored procedures mapped in Entity Framework using Database First. It creates strongly typed methods that you can call to run the stored procedures. I've run into a significant problem, however, in that I don't see any way to call these methods it created with the default parameters defined in the stored procedures. This means:

a) I have to manually add the default parameters to the method calls, which is brittle, if the default parameter value were to ever change.

b) Write method overloads by hand. This basically eliminates the benefit of generating a model from the database in the first place.

Does anyone know if there is a better solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: you can always set a default value for an entity property through the properties window.Does that not help you.?

Comment: That would still involve me manually entering a default value- if the default value of the proc ever changed there would be no way to automatically keep it synchronized with the model.

Comment: Could you write procs that provide you with the default values from the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Jan 2013, there's no supported way to do have the Entity Framework do this.

I have opened a feature request [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/805).

Comment: Maybe you already know it but.. due to migration, they've closed your ticket and it should be re-open in the github community if you want it to be considered again https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues

Comment: this site is not available

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hacky workaround. I don't know if there's a feature in EF to support optional parameters, but you can try to emulate it - if you're willing to change the stored procedures.

You can change the default value in the definition of the stored procedure to `NULL`, and then in the body of the procedure, replace `NULL` parameters with the desired default value. Then from the code using EF you could pass `null` to indicate using the default. This way at least the default is only defined in the SP itself.

Drawbacks include of course that now `NULL` becomes an "out-of-band" value, meaning you can't actually pass it to the SP if that's what you need (besides having to change your SPs and ensuring all future ones use this weird convention)

Comment: Yes, I actually proposed doing just this but it causes other complications for us so it's not an option unfortunately.